# Are there any verses in the Quran that address temptation and how to prevent temptation?

Tags: world

My city is full of people who do haram things all the time (seemingly) unknowingly. People smoke, do drugs, box, watch haram films, fight, dont dress modestly, talk to people of the opposite gender in an immodest manner, go out with girlfriends frequently. Getting into the more major side people commit zina (really really frequent), drink alcohol (not as common but still) etc. Some of these things a lot of people on social media such as having relationships, dressing, talking, films, drugs etc and sometimes it can be tempting especially when they are so often associated with freedom and things that are wonderful/bring joy and excitement to your life. Sometimes its hard to keep in check and this in turn may lead people into other haram acts.

Are there any verses in the Quran that address the whole idea of being tempted and how to prevent temptation?

Answer (score 0):

Assalamualaikum my brother.

Alhamdulillah. Allah has provided us opportunity to discuss on this question. Let us pray to Allah so that we may be kept from all evil deeds.

Regarding your questions on temptation, I would relate this scenario and idea with Quran verses on ***Al-Ma'roof*** and ***Al-Mungkar***.

Allah has described the believers as denouncing evil and as enjoining what is good. He says (interpretation of the meaning):

> *“The believers, men and women, are Awliyaa’ (helpers, supporters, friends, protectors) of one another; they enjoin (on the people)
>   Al‑Ma‘roof (i.e. Islamic Monotheism and all that Islam orders one to
>   do), and forbid (people) from Al‑Munkar (i.e. polytheism and disbelief
>   of all kinds, and all that Islam has forbidden)”*
>
> **[al-Tawbah 9:71]**

There are many verses which speak of enjoining what is good and forbidding what is evil; that is because of the importance of this issue and the great need that exists for it.

According to a saheeh hadeeth, the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said:

> “Whoever among you sees an evil action, let him change it with his
>   hand [by taking action]; if he cannot, then with his tongue [by
>   speaking out]; and if he cannot, then with his heart [by at least
>   hating it and believing that it is wrong], and that is the weakest of
>   faith.” Narrated by Muslim in his Saheeh.

**Changing evil by one's hand** should be done by those who are able to do that, such as those in positions of authority and the bodies in charge of such matters in the areas over which they have been appointed, the ruler in the area over which he has been appointed, the judge in the area over which he has been appointed, and by a man in his own house with his children and the members of his household, as much as he can.

But if he is not able to do that, or if changing it with his hand will lead to fitnah (tribulation) and conflict, and cause more harm than good, then he should not change it with his hand, rather he should **change it with his tongue**, by speaking out. That will be sufficient lest changing it with his hand will lead to a worse evil that that which he is seeking to change. This was stated by the scholars.

In the case of changing evil with his tongue, it is sufficient for him to say, “O my brother, fear Allah, this is not permitted, you should stop this, you should do such and such” and other good words spoken in a proper manner.

After the tongue comes the **heart**, i.e., hating the evil in one's heart, showing that one hates it, and not sitting with those who do it. All of these come under the heading of changing it with one's heart. And Allah is the Source of strength.

Reference : https://islamqa.info/index.php/en/answers/33757/changing-evil-by-ones-hand

Wallahualam.

Comment: You didnt really answer the question, Im asking for verses about temptation not about doing good and bad.